Python SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED macos 14.1
I have tried every suggestion I could find online but I keep getting the same error when I try to run yfinance or alpha vantage.
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 589, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 519, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.alphavantage.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=0E73047QK1NWEOPJ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Matteo's-SSD/python/prodg/experiment/pythonProject/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 620, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.alphavantage.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=key (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)')))


This error shows up both using python directly and after installing anaconda. I have already tried uninstalling all python versions I had and of course I have run the Install Certificates.command but nothing seams to solve the issue. I am using python 12.4 on macos 14.1
I have tried uninstalling all versions of python and reinstalling, I have tried installing anaconda and running the Install Certificates.command
